# Risk considerations with using Hotjar tracking service

Tags: web-application, javascript, user-tracking

Recently have received requested to implement Hotjar service on our e-commerce solution. This is a user tracking / heatmap tracking service that essential tracks all user interactions with your site via some javascript that is included on the page.

To block specific fields or site elements they provide examples such as

```
var blockFromHotjar = ['#details','.user-info','input[type="text"]','textarea'];  
$.each(blockFromHotjar,function(i,val){
$(val).attr('data-hj-masked','');
});
<!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for www.yoursite.com -->
```

Anyone implement this service before?